# VIM: Indentation changes when opening Python files

Tags: vim

when I open Python files my indentation changes. I have the following vimrc settings:

```
set number
colorscheme wombat256mod
set guifont=Consolas\ 11
set linespace=2
filetype on
filetype plugin on

au BufRead,BufNewFile *py,*pyw,*.c,*.h set tabstop=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set expandtab
fu Select_c_style()
    if search('^\t', 'n', 150)
    set shiftwidth=8
    set noexpandtab
    el 
    set shiftwidth=4
    set expandtab
    en
endf
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c,*.h call Select_c_style()
au BufRead,BufNewFile Makefile* set noexpandtab
highlight BadWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw match BadWhitespace /^\t\+/
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h set textwidth=79
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c,*.h set formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=o formatoptions-=r
au BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h set fileformat=unix
let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on
filetype indent on
set autoindent
```

Anybody see something that can cause it?

For example I open an *.html file the indentation is a tab. But once I opened any Python file and go back to the html file the indentation switches to python preferences.

Comment: You have a _ton_ of lines setting indentation - why did you put them there if you didn't know what they did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The au lines with *.py in them are what are changing your settings.  Notably,

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*pyw set shiftwidth=4
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set expandtab
```

You need to "undo" these settings when opening HTML files.  Just add a few more autocmds that work on *.html to set noexpandtab and set your shiftwidth back to 8.

Answer (score 3):

I have an addition to @dash-tom-bang's answer: both shiftwidth and expandtab options are local to buffer. No need to add any autocommands, just change all `set` statements with `setlocal`, so it will not alter the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for this ZyX, as I've been struggling with a similar set of problems (notably my formatting for .txt files leaking into other file buffers).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/Vim/vimrc at some place and sourcing it from .vimrc. That should save hassles.

EDIT: Oh, well apparently, that's already something you're doing!

Comment: I don't understand could you explain how your answer will stop my indentation change when I opened a Python file?